# Two floating div's, one underneath. works in every browser except IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

So I have an html-structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="contact-wrapper">
    <div>
        <h4>België</h4>

        <p>Tuinwijklaan 79<br />
        9000 Gent<br />
        Tel. 0468/115967<br />
         info@echomedic.be<br />
         </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Nederland</h4>

        <p>Kerkstraat 423-C<br />
        1017 HX Amsterdam<br />
        Tel: +32 468 11 59 67<br />
         info@echomedic.nl </p>
    </div><br />
    <a id="link-contact" href="#">Contacteer ons</a>
</div>
```

The two div's are displayed next to each other, and the link under it, like this:

[image: Divs like it should be]

But in ie9 it shows like this:

[image: ie9 divs]

This is my css for the divs:

```
footer div#contact-wrapper, footer h1 {
    float: left;
}

footer div#contact-wrapper div {
    margin: 16px 0px 0px 45px;
    float: left;
}

footer div#contact-wrapper div:first-of-type {
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    border-right: 1px dashed #a3b0b9;
}

footer div#contact-wrapper a#link-contact {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ffffff url('../img/contact-arrow.gif') no-repeat 95% center;
    border: 4px solid #bbc2c7;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #bbc2c7;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 60px;
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 5px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: You should always clear after floating elements. See Henrik Ammer's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `<br>` and add this to your CSS:

```
footer div#contact-wrapper a#link-contact {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Everything stays the same. The link is still next to the others.

Comment: Missed that the `<a>` was set to `display: inline-block;`. If you set it to `display: block;` it works. Edited answer accordingly.